# Can I use xpath (in lxml) to find the names of tags not known at the start?

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I have some xml files I am trying to process.  Unfortunately I do not have full access to all of the different elements that constitute all of the possible trees

so for example I might have a document that is structured

```
<typeOfBook>
    <isMystery>True</isMystery>
</typeofBook>
```

Easy enough, but when I look at the checklist that was used in the initial creation of these files I see categories under the section Type of Book such as Reference Spirituality.  Given my experience with the Mystery I try to write an xpath expression

I build my xpath based on this

```
'//typeofbook/isreferencespirituality/text()'
```

then I discover that the actual tag they used was isrefspirit thus the correct xpath is

```
'//typeofbook/isrefspirit/text()'
```

Given the number of files and possible number of categories I am trying to learn is there is an **xpath fishing tool** - I would like to run through all of my files once to find all tags after type of book so I can correctly classify the text that is returned

basically I would like to do something like

Run some query on all of my documents to find the * in the following line

```
'//typeofbook/*/'
```

Comment: `'//typeofbook/*' ` would return all the tags inside the typeofbook tags.

Comment: wow on the right track but I dropped it - thanks post as answer and I will credit you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `*` is used as a *wildcard* so just `//typeofbook/*'` will get all the child elements inside of the `typeofbook` tags.

There are a couple of of other things for unknown nodes that you might find useful:

```
@* # any attribute 
node() # any node at all
```